# Tox: cannot invoke Jython and PyPy through tox

Tags: python, jython, pypy, tox

I try to invoke Python2.7, PyPy and Jython through a tox test.
The tests work perfectly with Python 2.7, however, it always raises an Import- or AssertationError for PyPy and Jython. I found a similiar error report [here](https://bitbucket.org/hpk42/tox/issue/9/virtualenv-creation-failure-under-pypy) which states that the ImportError should be solved with PyPy 1.5.

My error concerning PyPy:

```
actionid=pypy
msg=getenv
cmdargs=['/usr/lib64/pypy-2.0.2/pypy', '/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv.py', '--setuptools', 'pypy']
env={'GNOME_DESKTOP_SESSION_ID': 'this-is-deprecated', 'GJS_DEBUG_OUTPUT': 'stderr', 'LESSOPEN': '||/usr/bin/lesspipe.sh %s', 'QT_IM_MODULE': 'ibus', 'LOGNAME': '...', 'USER': 'robbe', 'GNOME_KEYRING_CONTROL': '/run/user/...', 'XDG_VTNR': '1', 'PATH': '/home/...coding_dojo/.tox/pypy/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/home/.../.local/bin:/home/.../bin', 'WINDOWPATH': '1', 'LANG': 'en_US.utf8', 'TERM': 'xterm-256color', 'SHELL': '/bin/bash', 'XAUTHORITY': '/root/.xauthANoa2X', 'SESSION_MANAGER': 'local/unix:@/tmp/.ICE-unix/1629,unix/unix:/tmp/.ICE-unix/1629', 'SHLVL': '3', 'HISTSIZE': '1000', 'WINDOWID': '37748742', 'XMODIFIERS': '@im=ibus', 'GPG_AGENT_INFO': '/run/user/1000/keyring-S3HIKy/gpg:0:1', 'HOME': '/root', 'USERNAME': '...', 'XDG_RUNTIME_DIR': '/run/user/1000', 'SSH_AUTH_SOCK': '/run/.../ssh', 'VTE_VERSION': '3406', 'GDMSESSION': 'gnome', 'MAIL': '/var/spool/mail/robbe', 'QT_GRAPHICSSYSTEM_CHECKED': '1', 'XDG_SESSION_ID': '1', 'DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS': 'unix:abstract=/tmp/dbus-jKoHF6ufGh,guid=cf0f26...54ce0d6...73db51d96765', '_': '/usr/bin/tox', 'DESKTOP_SESSION': 'gnome', 'DISPLAY': ':0', 'GNOME_KEYRING_PID': '1625', 'HOSTNAME': 'localhost.localdomain', 'GDM_LANG': 'en_US.utf8', 'HISTCONTROL': 'ignoredups', 'PWD': '/home/.../coding_dojo', 'COLORTERM': 'gnome-terminal', 'XDG_MENU_PREFIX': 'gnome-', 'LS_COLORS': 'rs=0:di=38;5;27:ln=38;5;51:mh=44;38;5;15:pi=40;38;5;11:so=38;5;13:do=38;5;5:bd=48;5;232;38;5;11:cd=48;5;232;38;5;3:or=48;5;232;38;5;9:mi=05;48;5;232;38;5;15:su=48;5;196;38;5;15:sg=48;5;11;38;5;16:ca=48;5;196;38;5;226:tw=48;5;10;38;5;16:ow=48;5;10;38;5;21:st=48;5;21;38;5;15:ex=38;5;34:*.tar=38;5;9:*.tgz=38;5;9:*.arc=38;5;9:*.arj=38;5;9:*.taz=38;5;9:*.lha=38;5;9:*.lzh=38;5;9:*.lzma=38;5;9:*.tlz=38;5;9:*.txz=38;5;9:*.tzo=38;5;9:*.t7z=38;5;9:*.zip=38;5;9:*.z=38;5;9:*.Z=38;5;9:*.dz=38;5;9:*.gz=38;5;9:*.lrz=38;5;9:*.lz=38;5;9:*.lzo=38;5;9:*.xz=38;5;9:*.bz2=38;5;9:*.bz=38;5;9:*.tbz=38;5;9:*.tbz2=38;5;9:*.tz=38;5;9:*.deb=38;5;9:*.rpm=38;5;9:*.jar=38;5;9:*.war=38;5;9:*.ear=38;5;9:*.sar=38;5;9:*.rar=38;5;9:*.alz=38;5;9:*.ace=38;5;9:*.zoo=38;5;9:*.cpio=38;5;9:*.7z=38;5;9:*.rz=38;5;9:*.cab=38;5;9:*.jpg=38;5;13:*.jpeg=38;5;13:*.gif=38;5;13:*.bmp=38;5;13:*.pbm=38;5;13:*.pgm=38;5;13:*.ppm=38;5;13:*.tga=38;5;13:*.xbm=38;5;13:*.xpm=38;5;13:*.tif=38;5;13:*.tiff=38;5;13:*.png=38;5;13:*.svg=38;5;13:*.svgz=38;5;13:*.mng=38;5;13:*.pcx=38;5;13:*.mov=38;5;13:*.mpg=38;5;13:*.mpeg=38;5;13:*.m2v=38;5;13:*.mkv=38;5;13:*.ogm=38;5;13:*.mp4=38;5;13:*.m4v=38;5;13:*.mp4v=38;5;13:*.vob=38;5;13:*.qt=38;5;13:*.nuv=38;5;13:*.wmv=38;5;13:*.asf=38;5;13:*.rm=38;5;13:*.rmvb=38;5;13:*.flc=38;5;13:*.avi=38;5;13:*.fli=38;5;13:*.flv=38;5;13:*.gl=38;5;13:*.dl=38;5;13:*.xcf=38;5;13:*.xwd=38;5;13:*.yuv=38;5;13:*.cgm=38;5;13:*.emf=38;5;13:*.axv=38;5;13:*.anx=38;5;13:*.ogv=38;5;13:*.ogx=38;5;13:*.aac=38;5;45:*.au=38;5;45:*.flac=38;5;45:*.mid=38;5;45:*.midi=38;5;45:*.mka=38;5;45:*.mp3=38;5;45:*.mpc=38;5;45:*.ogg=38;5;45:*.ra=38;5;45:*.wav=38;5;45:*.axa=38;5;45:*.oga=38;5;45:*.spx=38;5;45:*.xspf=38;5;45:', 'GJS_DEBUG_TOPICS': 'JS ERROR;JS LOG', 'XDG_SEAT': 'seat0'}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "app_main.py", line 72, in run_toplevel
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 2577, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 979, in main
    no_pip=options.no_pip)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 1081, in create_environment
    site_packages=site_packages, clear=clear))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 1256, in install_python
    fix_lib64(lib_dir)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 1643, in fix_lib64
    "Unexpected python lib dir: %r" % lib_dir)
```

My error log for Jython

```
actionid=jython
msg=getenv
cmdargs=['/usr/bin/jython', '/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv.py', '--setuptools', 'jython']
env={'GNOME_DESKTOP_SESSION_ID': 'this-is-deprecated', 'GJS_DEBUG_OUTPUT': 'stderr', 'LESSOPEN': '||/usr/bin/lesspipe.sh %s', 'QT_IM_MODULE': 'ibus', 'LOGNAME': 'robbe', 'USER': '...', 'GNOME_KEYRING_CONTROL': '/run/user/...', 'XDG_VTNR': '1', 'PATH': '/home/.../coding_dojo/.tox/jython/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/home/.../.local/bin:/home/.../bin', 'WINDOWPATH': '1', 'LANG': 'en_US.utf8', 'TERM': 'xterm-256color', 'SHELL': '/bin/bash', 'XAUTHORITY': '/root/.xauthANoa2X', 'SESSION_MANAGER': 'local/unix:@/tmp/.ICE-unix/1629,unix/unix:/tmp/.ICE-unix/1629', 'SHLVL': '3', 'HISTSIZE': '1000', 'WINDOWID': '37748742', 'XMODIFIERS': '@im=ibus', 'GPG_AGENT_INFO': '/run/.../gpg:0:1', 'HOME': '/root', 'USERNAME': '...', 'XDG_RUNTIME_DIR': '/run/user/1000', 'SSH_AUTH_SOCK': '/run/.../ssh', 'VTE_VERSION': '3406', 'GDMSESSION': 'gnome', , 'QT_GRAPHICSSYSTEM_CHECKED': '1', 'XDG_SESSION_ID': '1', 'DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS': 'unix:abstract=/tmp/dbus-...', '_': '/usr/bin/tox', 'DESKTOP_SESSION': 'gnome', 'DISPLAY': ':0', 'GNOME_KEYRING_PID': '1625', 'HOSTNAME': 'localhost.localdomain', 'GDM_LANG': 'en_US.utf8', 'HISTCONTROL': 'ignoredups', 'PWD': '/home/.../coding_dojo', 'COLORTERM': 'gnome-terminal', 'XDG_MENU_PREFIX': 'gnome-', 'LS_COLORS': 'rs=0:di=38;5;27:ln=38;5;51:mh=44;38;5;15:pi=40;38;5;11:so=38;5;13:do=38;5;5:bd=48;5;232;38;5;11:cd=48;5;232;38;5;3:or=48;5;232;38;5;9:mi=05;48;5;232;38;5;15:su=48;5;196;38;5;15:sg=48;5;11;38;5;16:ca=48;5;196;38;5;226:tw=48;5;10;38;5;16:ow=48;5;10;38;5;21:st=48;5;21;38;5;15:ex=38;5;34:*.tar=38;5;9:*.tgz=38;5;9:*.arc=38;5;9:*.arj=38;5;9:*.taz=38;5;9:*.lha=38;5;9:*.lzh=38;5;9:*.lzma=38;5;9:*.tlz=38;5;9:*.txz=38;5;9:*.tzo=38;5;9:*.t7z=38;5;9:*.zip=38;5;9:*.z=38;5;9:*.Z=38;5;9:*.dz=38;5;9:*.gz=38;5;9:*.lrz=38;5;9:*.lz=38;5;9:*.lzo=38;5;9:*.xz=38;5;9:*.bz2=38;5;9:*.bz=38;5;9:*.tbz=38;5;9:*.tbz2=38;5;9:*.tz=38;5;9:*.deb=38;5;9:*.rpm=38;5;9:*.jar=38;5;9:*.war=38;5;9:*.ear=38;5;9:*.sar=38;5;9:*.rar=38;5;9:*.alz=38;5;9:*.ace=38;5;9:*.zoo=38;5;9:*.cpio=38;5;9:*.7z=38;5;9:*.rz=38;5;9:*.cab=38;5;9:*.jpg=38;5;13:*.jpeg=38;5;13:*.gif=38;5;13:*.bmp=38;5;13:*.pbm=38;5;13:*.pgm=38;5;13:*.ppm=38;5;13:*.tga=38;5;13:*.xbm=38;5;13:*.xpm=38;5;13:*.tif=38;5;13:*.tiff=38;5;13:*.png=38;5;13:*.svg=38;5;13:*.svgz=38;5;13:*.mng=38;5;13:*.pcx=38;5;13:*.mov=38;5;13:*.mpg=38;5;13:*.mpeg=38;5;13:*.m2v=38;5;13:*.mkv=38;5;13:*.ogm=38;5;13:*.mp4=38;5;13:*.m4v=38;5;13:*.mp4v=38;5;13:*.vob=38;5;13:*.qt=38;5;13:*.nuv=38;5;13:*.wmv=38;5;13:*.asf=38;5;13:*.rm=38;5;13:*.rmvb=38;5;13:*.flc=38;5;13:*.avi=38;5;13:*.fli=38;5;13:*.flv=38;5;13:*.gl=38;5;13:*.dl=38;5;13:*.xcf=38;5;13:*.xwd=38;5;13:*.yuv=38;5;13:*.cgm=38;5;13:*.emf=38;5;13:*.axv=38;5;13:*.anx=38;5;13:*.ogv=38;5;13:*.ogx=38;5;13:*.aac=38;5;45:*.au=38;5;45:*.flac=38;5;45:*.mid=38;5;45:*.midi=38;5;45:*.mka=38;5;45:*.mp3=38;5;45:*.mpc=38;5;45:*.ogg=38;5;45:*.ra=38;5;45:*.wav=38;5;45:*.axa=38;5;45:*.oga=38;5;45:*.spx=38;5;45:*.xspf=38;5;45:', 'GJS_DEBUG_TOPICS': 'JS ERROR;JS LOG', 'XDG_SEAT': 'seat0'}
Traceback (innermost last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 14, in ?
ImportError: no module named optparse
```

Can you give me a recommendation what I should change?

I use [PyPy 2.0.2 with GCC 4.8.1 20130603 (Red Hat 4.8.1-1)], Jython 2.2.1 on java1.7.0_25 and tox 1.5.0.

Answer (score 0):

The virtualenv issue with PyPy comes from using a too old version of virtualenv.  Try with the latest virtualenv instead.

Comment: I reinstalled virtualenv using version 1.9.1. But I still get the same error.

Comment: I can't say for sure, but `/usr/lib/python2.7` should probably not appear at all with PyPy.  It's like running CPython 2.5 or 2.6 and getting paths with `python2.7` in them.  Can you give a way to reproduce the error?